# Get icon of installed apps on WebOS TV LG

Tags: webos

I'm making a sample about remote on LG TV using webOS with ConnectSDK. I can remote with some basic command, get the list of installed apps on the TV. The data of each item like this:

```
["type": native, "handlesRelaunch": 0, "uiRevision": 2, "deeplinkingParams": {"contentTarget":"https://www.youtube.com/tv?launch=search&v=$CONTENTID"}, "wolwowlan": 1, "icon": https://192.168.100.71:3001/resources/ed06d6cb588bfaac4181742c2266ba1586671791/yt_lg_80x80.png, "checkUpdateOnLaunch": 1, "icons": <__NSArray0 0x7fff8062d430>(

)
, "inAppSetting": 0, "id": youtube.leanback.v4, "splashBackground": 2018-new-splash-solid-grey-LG.png, "supportQuickStart": 1, "version": 1.3.86, "systemApp": 0, "hasPromotion": 0, "removable": 1, "unmovable": 0, "dialAppName": YouTube, "lockable": 1, "bgImage": 9262051282473701_youtube_leanback_preview.png, "trustLevel": default, "resolution": 1280x720, "inspectable": 0, "binId": 972014, "vendor": LG Electronics, "defaultWindowType": card, "main": cobalt, "tileSize": normal, "installTime": 1587515064, "spinnerOnLaunch": 1, "privilegedJail": 1, "imageForRecents": 9262051307371701_youtube_leanback_splash.png, "folderPath": /media/cryptofs/apps/usr/palm/applications/youtube.leanback.v4, "title": YouTube, "appsize": 24847139, "disableBackHistoryAPI": 0, "nativeLifeCycleInterfaceVersion": 2, "largeIcon": yt_lg_130x130.png, "transparent": 0, "iconColor": #ffffff, "mediumLargeIcon": 15290169578796633_16977867_115x115.png, "accessibility": {
    supportsAudioGuidance = 0;
}, "enablePigScreenSaver": 0, "noSplashOnLaunch": 0, "CPApp": 0, "visible": 1, "requiredEULA": generalTerms]
```

With above data, I have url of icon: `https://192.168.100.71:3001/resources/ed06d6cb588bfaac4181742c2266ba1586671791/yt_lg_80x80.png`

But I can't get icon from this url, like this issue:
https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-iOS/issues/191

I can't find any document about this.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I got the URLs, but couldn't download the icons. I was manually sending commands to the TV instead of using Connect SDK, but I think it's the same problem.

I finally realized that sending the `listApps` command to the TV doesn't provide working icon URLs, but the `listLaunchPoints` command *does*.

So in my case I can send the following WebSocket payload (assuming I already connected to the TV and sent the `register` message):
`{"type": "request", "id": "[A RANDOM UUID]", "uri": "ssap://com.webos.applicationManager/listLaunchPoints", "payload": {}}`

And the resulting icon URLs work as expected.

I'm not sure if the `listLaunchPoints` command is available in Connect SDK for iOS. I noticed that it *is* in the Android version.